# How to find a specific value of a JSON property which is in a directory?

Tags: c#, json

JSON:

```
{
  "id": 1,
  "name": "RobloHunks",
  "description": "",
  "owner": {
    "buildersClubMembershipType": "None",
    "userId": 1179762,
    "username": "RobloTim",
    "displayName": "RobloTim"
  },
  "shout": null,
  "memberCount": 15915,
  "isBuildersClubOnly": false,
  "publicEntryAllowed": true
}
```

What I want to print:

```
RobloTim
```

Well, value of 'username' in the 'owner' directory.

Comment: You need to check, Serialize and Deserialize  https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/serialization/system-text-json-how-to

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are a few ways, one of them involving creating models and deserializeing.

But if you only need 1 property, this will work:

```
dynamic obj = JObject.Parse(yourJson);
string userName = obj.owner.username
Console.WriteLine(userName);
```

You will need the [NewtonSoft.Json package](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Newtonsoft.Json)

> PM> Install-Package Newtonsoft.Json

Comment: Thanks you so much! This really helped a lot and I will be using this method because it's 1 line of code to convert to a nicer way of doing it! I will be marking this as correct answer when it let's me.

Answer (score 1):

Deserlize the result to the following object like the following..

https://json2csharp.com/

```
Root myDeserializedClass = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Root>(myJsonResponse); 
public class Owner    {
    public string buildersClubMembershipType { get; set; } 
    public int userId { get; set; } 
    public string username { get; set; } 
    public string displayName { get; set; } 
}

public class Root    {
    public int id { get; set; } 
    public string name { get; set; } 
    public string description { get; set; } 
    public Owner owner { get; set; } 
    public object shout { get; set; } 
    public int memberCount { get; set; } 
    public bool isBuildersClubOnly { get; set; } 
    public bool publicEntryAllowed { get; set; } 
}
```

Answer (score 0):

i had to do the same earlier, i did it by creating a class and converting all - by using a JSONConverter library - into that class, there are json to class converters around, i dont want to commercialise anything but they are quite easy to find